# How to use filter in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an app in ionic v1 and I am upgrading into ionic 4. In my app have a filter and I want to write in ionic 4.

ionic 1 ==>

```
var ans = $filter('filter')(this.examData.exam.students[0].answers, { question_id: quationTemp.id });
```

and showing this error:

```
Cannot find name '$filter'.ts(2304)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like  this

```
var ans = this.examData.exam.students[0].answers.filter( ans => ans.question_id === quationTemp.id )
```